# Why should the following block of code return false?

Tags: java, return, boolean

```
public boolean monkeyTrouble (boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) {
    if (aSmile && bSmile) {
        return true;
    }
    if  (!aSmile && !bSmile) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't understand why that last line of code should `return false;`

Can anyone explain? Thank you.

Comment: Because if only one of the monkeys is smiling, then there is no monkey trouble

Comment: Create a truth table. A table that shows all 4 possible combinations of input values. Then manually compute the result of the method. Then check the rows that result in false...

Comment: You can return true if you want. But then the two first blocks would be useless since it would always return true. We can't tell you what your own method, which has no clear documentation, should return. It's your choice. What is the method supposed to do?

Comment: As an aside: you can simplify the code to `return aSmile == bSmile;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the problem description:

> We are in trouble if they are both smiling or if neither of them is smiling. Return true if we are in trouble.

Therefore if one of them are smiling, we are not in trouble.

```
if (aSmile && bSmile) {
   return true;
}
```

Covers if both of them are smiling. And:

```
if  (!aSmile && !bSmile) {
    return true;
}
```

Covers if neither of them are smiling. These are the only two combinations for which the method should return true. So if neither of these conditions are true, you need to return false.

Comment: Oh, so is that sort of like an "else-statement"? Since that's the only other possibility

Comment: @Sam It's similar to that. It just isn't written with an `else` since if any of the `if` statements are true it will `return` and exit the method, so it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

create a truth table and check what happens

```
aSmile bSmile 
true true 
true false 
false true 
false false
```

case 1: `monkeyTrouble (true, true)`

```
 if (aSmile && bSmile) {
        return true;
```

case 2: `monkeyTrouble (true , false)`

```
 return false
```

case 3: `monkeyTrouble (false, true)`

```
return false
```

case 4: `monkeyTrouble (false, false)`

```
  if  (!aSmile && !bSmile) {
            return true;
```

that is why the last statement is executed in two cases.